# APC apc_fetch blocked whilst file upload in progress

Tags: php, apc

I'm trying to do the simple file upload progress using the php-apc module.  I'm doing everything to the book, seems to work ok, but I've tracked down the problem to `apc_fetch()` being blocked whilst the file is being uploaded.

I've tested it with a 20mb upload in one browser tab, and a request to a url that spits out a timestamp.  I can make multiple requests to the timestamp url and they all complete and return a response.  If I switch it to the progress url which outputs the value of the apc cache upload value, it will return when the item has not been cached and the upload has not started - it returns false.  As soon as the upload starts, it seems that `apc_fetch()` on that cache key just gets blocked until the upload has finished.  As soon as the upload finishes the request will return but with the status of the finished file.

I've tried setting `apc.rfc1867_freq` to different values but the blocking problem still occurs.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?  I'm going to have to pause work on this and look at alternatives.

Cheers!

Comment: Post code for form and for processing file loading.

Comment: Hmm. possibly a session file lock issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the PHP upload extension!

http://www.ultramegatech.com/2010/10/create-an-upload-progress-bar-with-php-and-jquery/